# Swift 3 xcode 8 failed to import Lock and RxSwift in to my project

Tags: swift3, cocoapods, xcode8, importerror

In my project, created by other, i have problems with some libraries that i'm "podding" them in my pod file, using cocoapod.
this is my pod file

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, "9.3"

target 'classme' do
    use_frameworks!
    inhibit_all_warnings!
    pod 'Firebase/Core'
    pod 'Firebase/Database'
    pod 'Firebase/Storage'
    pod 'Firebase/DynamicLinks'
    pod 'Firebase/Auth'
    pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
    pod 'Lock'
    pod 'RxSwift'
    pod 'RxCocoa'
    pod 'RxDataSources'
    pod 'Auth0'
    pod 'HockeySDK'
    pod 'MaterialControls'
    pod 'libPhoneNumber-iOS'
    pod 'SwiftLint'
    pod 'Mixpanel-swift'
    pod ‘AppsFlyerFramework’
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3.0'
    end
  end
end
```

When trying to import the Lock i get the following message

No such module 'Lock'

Also for the RxSwift

How it can be solved?

Answer (score 0):

I have used the myApp.xcworkspace instead of myApp.xcodeproj and the problem fixed.